# Pointing API Gateway to specific version of a function or an alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a Lambda function using terraform like so:

```
module "my-lambda" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version = "~> v1.31.0"

  function_name         = "${var.environment_name}-${local.lambda_name}"
...
  publish               = true
}

#...
module "alias" {
  source           = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws//modules/alias"
  name             = "${var.lambda_name}-latest"
  function_name    = module.my-lambda.this_lambda_function_name
  function_version = module.my-lambda.this_lambda_function_version
}
```

so presently I have a published Lambda version with a number, to which I also added an alias, and also `$LATEST` version. The reason I need the published version is that Provisioned Concurrency can be only attached to a published version.

My API gateway integration looks like:

```
module "api_gateway" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/apigateway-v2/aws"
  version = "~> 0.9.0"

  name          = "${var.environment_name}-my-api"
  # ...Abriged...
  integrations = {
    "GET /mymethod" = {
      integration_type        = "AWS_PROXY"
      integration_http_method = "POST"
      payload_format_version  = "2.0"
      lambda_arn              = module.my-lambda.this_lambda_function_invoke_arn
    }
}
```

However in console I can see that it is triggering the `$LATEST` version, not the published one. How I can alter the configuration so that a particular version (or alias) is triggered by the API Gateway integration?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with terraform but to invoke alias from api gateway you need to have lambda alias arn in API gateway integration.

You are getting lambda arn from lambda module but you need arn of alias.

`lambda_arn = module.my-lambda.this_lambda_function_invoke_arn`

Alias arn is nothing but `<Lambda ARN>:<AliasName>`.

So you try taking arn from module.alias or append alias name and lambda arn with `:` in integrations.